# Preserving session between node.js server reboots

Tags: node.js

I'm developing a node.js app and I use nodemon to run it. My question is how I do to keep the session open when I make a change in the server, and nodemon reboot.

Comment: Use a session store. If your sessions are stored in memory then dump them before you reboot and restore them afterwards.

Comment: Try to add nginx as a proxy server, that will keep connection until server restarts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*This answer assumes that you're using Express or Koa, two of the more popular node.js web frameworks*.

In your application, you probably have a line that says the following.

**Express 4**

```
var app = require( 'express' )()
var session = require( 'express-session' )
app.use( session() ) // this is the session middleware
```

**KoaJS**

```
var app = require( 'koa' )()
var session = require( 'koa-session' )
app.use( session() ) // this is the session middleware
```

The guiding wisdom in web applications is to make the world-facing side of it as **stateless** as possible. This means that your node.js server holds no information between requests and can be destroyed and restarted anytime.

A session is a very **stateful** thing. Because of this, you need to store session data in something designed to keep the data uncorrupted in the long run. This is most commonly done through a database (more secure) or a browser cookie (less secure).

The [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) module holds session information in memory by default. This violates the stateless ideals and will lose session information on reboot.

The [koa-session](https://github.com/koajs/session) module uses cookies by default. This is stateless, but raises some security concerns in that it may be possible for users to modify their own session variables, so don't use this for billing or other sensitive operations.

In both of the above modules, you can override the defaults with your own *session store*.

### Redis Session Store

I normally store session data in a database like [redis](http://redis.io/).

**Express**

This can be easily wired into express with a module like [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis).

Quoting from the Readme:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

**KoaJS**

Using redis to store session data is also possible in koa with the [koa-redis](https://github.com/koajs/koa-redis) module.
Paraphrasing from the Readme:

```
var app require('koa')();
var session = require('koa-generic-session');
var redisStore = require('koa-redis');

app.keys = ['keys', 'keykeys'];

app.use(session({
  store: redisStore()
}));

app.use(function *() {
  this.session.name = 'koa-redis';
});
```

### No Databases Session Store

**Express**

Express can store session data in cookies with the [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) extension.

**Koa**

As mentioned before, the [koa-session](https://github.com/koajs/session) module stores sessions in cookies by default.

Comment: In Koa how we can use the session inside a required module ?

Comment: @Ahmad As long as the middleware uses `this.session` or `req.session` (koa and nodejs respectively), it can access the session.